# Access denied when accessing folder - MAC

Tags: c#, macos, console, mono

I run on mono and I need to Crete folder and extract zipped files in there. However I am getting this exception. I get that the access is denied but I can't fins the solution for this, everything is windows . The folder is created but I can create file in there.  However if I create only a file then I can write in it

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/pat/Documents/Work/TestConsole/PdftronTestConsole/NewDirectory1/' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

var path = "/Users/pat/Documents/Work/TestConsole/PdftronTestConsole/NewDirectory1/";

 Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //Read embedded resources
                inStream = new BufferedStream(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resFileName));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                outStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get access denied because `var path = "/Users/pat/Documents/Work/TestConsole/PdftronTestConsole/NewDirectory1/";` isn't a file. When you open a filestream from the harddrive, you need to specify a filename in the filestream. Otherwise the program doesn't know where the stream need to be saved.

For example:

```
var path = "/Users/pat/Documents/Work/TestConsole/PdftronTestConsole/NewDirectory1/";
string pathWithFileName = Path.Combine(path, "text.txt");
using (var stream = new FileStream(pathWithFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    // Do whatever to write to the file.
}
```

After this change I could access to my documents folder and other folders with C#.